# Google Workspace ChromeOS Devices link to Hornbill

Tags: google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, chromebook, google-workspace-add-ons, google-admin-settings-api

I am trying to use the Asset Data Import Tool from Hornbill : https://wiki.hornbill.com/index.php?title=Asset_Data_Import_Tool

They have the option to import from Google Workspace. I just need to provide:

Customer - The Customer ID of the Google Account. Supports my_customer to return devices enrolled to the deafult account that the KeySafe key was created with

Query - Search string as per the Google API Documentation (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/chromeosdevices/list)

OrgUnitPath - The full path of the Google Organisational Unit where the devices reside

Can someone give me an example of what the Query and OrgUnitPath would look like please?

what I am doing currently says no devices found check your config.